# Append to table using unbound textbox

Tags: vba, ms-access, append

I am trying to append two data points to a table using unbound textboxes. I can get one to populate properly, but the other one is coming over blank.

For this example the Criteria1 = 1 and Criteria2 = 9/24/19

Here is my code:

```
Dim StrSQL As String
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set db = Application.CurrentDb

Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("3 - GRUpload")
Dim Criteria1 As String
Dim Criteria2 As String

Criteria1 = Me!GRValue
Criterial2 = Me!GRDate

StrSQL = "Insert Into [*Master Records - 2 - GRs] ([GR Value], [GR Date]) Values(" & Criteria1 & ", " & Criteria2 & ")"

qdf.SQL = StrSQL
```

I attached a picture of the resulting query, but this is SQL if that's more helpful:

```
INSERT INTO [*Master Records - 2 - GRs] ([GR Value], [GR Date])
Select 1 As Exp1, Criteria2 AS Expr2;
```

I have tried several variations of the code, including:

```
Values(""" & Criteria1 & """, """ & Criteria2 & """)"
```

Which results in:

```
INSERT INTO [*Master Records - 2 - GRs] ([GR Value], [GR Date])
Select "1" As Exp1, "" AS Expr2;
```

So I'm at a loss... Could one of you point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Comment: Use dot instead of ! (bang) to reference textboxes and you will get intellisense popup tips as you type: `Me.GRDate`.

Comment: Also Criteria2 has no value. It is not getting anything from textbox. What event is code in?

Answer (score 0):

Date/time type field requires # delimiter for parameters. Text type use apostrophe (or doubled quote), numbers none. Try:

```
StrSQL = "Insert Into [*Master Records - 2 - GRs] ([GR Value], [GR Date]) " & _
           Values(" & Criteria1 & ", #" & Criteria2 & "#)"
```

Strongly advise not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters in naming convention.

Comment: well, that changed it stuff, but didn't quite work. 

That gave me a result of "##" for criteria2